# create a new prompt in linux shell using c

Tags: c

I want to create a new prompt with a desired name in linux. And it should work like below.(if my executable name is out)

```
 original_shell$./out
 my_new_shell>give some input here
 ...
 ...
 some output
 ...
 my_new_shell>done
 original_shell$
```

How to do this using C, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you use bash ? If yes,  you can modify the environment variable PS1 to change your prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `setenv("PS1", "Your_new_prompt", 1);`

I didn't test it but I think it's ok.

Hope it help.

Comment: It won't work because it doesn't modify parent environment.

Comment: Obviously not if you don't use `execlp()` after calling `setenv()` but giving you clues to find the answer is smarter than giving you the answer without letting you look by yourself... It should actually be the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `system()` to run a new shell with `PS1` set:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("PS1='my_new_shell>' bash");
    return 0;
}
```

Or you can use `setenv()` and then exec the shell:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    setenv("PS1", "my_new_shell>", 1);
    execlp("bash", "bash", (char*)NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works in creating the new prompt. Thanks for the help! 
How can I exit the new shell with the command "done" ? I know it exits with the command "exit". And also how can I take any inputs into C program from the new shell?
Thanks again.